# Finding a limit inside a limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I'm having trouble with these kind of problems:

Given $\lim \limits_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x^2)-1}{x}=1$ find $\lim \limits_{x \to 4} f(x)$

Thank you!

Edit: What I've been doing so far is this:

$\frac{\lim \limits_{x \to 2}f(x^2)-1}{\lim \limits_{x \to 2}x}=\frac{f(4)-1}{2}=1$ 
So I just assumed that for that limit to be 1, $f(4)-1=2$, but I don't know how to apply that to find $\lim \limits_{x \to 4} f(x)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. When asking questions it's best to add where you have been going wrong. Do this in your question, not in the comment section, by adding your work so far.

Comment: Could you please give us more information about the first limit? Cause you said it was given although you didn't set it to any number.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to write what that first limit equals to, and I just added what I've been doing so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $g(x)=\frac{f(x^2)-1}{x}$ with $\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)=1$
Then:
$$f(x^2)=xg(x)+1$$
Passing limits:
$$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x^2)=\lim_{x\to 2}(xg(x)+1)=3$$
Substituting $y=x^2$:
$$\lim_{y\to 4}f(y)=3$$
So:
$$\lim_{x\to 4}f(x)=3$$

I alert you that when you did $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x^2)=f(4)$ is wrong, because you don't know that the function is defined at $x=4$ and you don't know that the function is continuous.

Comment: In this part: $$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x^2)=\lim_{x\to 2}(xg(x)+1)=3$$ how did you find that 3?

Comment: I did say form the first substitution that $lim_{x\to 2} g(x)=1$ which is just the limit that is given by the problem!

Comment: Oh, got it now!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Big pleasure to help you!!!!!!!