# Finding a limit inside a limit 2

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I'm stuck with this problem:

Given $\lim \limits_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x+2)+3f(x^2)}{x^2+1}=3$ find $\lim \limits_{x \to 4} f(x)$

I've alreadly asked this question (with a different example) ([Finding a limit inside a limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893593/finding-a-limit-inside-a-limit)) and I understood it perfectly, but I'm stuck in the last step:

$g(x)=\frac{f(x+2)+3f(x^2)}{x^2+1}$ with $\lim \limits_{x \to 2} g(x)=3$

Solving for $f$:

$f(x+2)+f(x^2)=\frac{g(x)(x^2+1)}{5}$

Now finding the limit as ${x \to 2}$

$\lim \limits_{x\to 2} \frac{g(x)(x^2+1)}{5}=\lim \limits_{x\to 2}f(x+2)+f(x^2)=3$

And now I have no idea what to do...

$\lim \limits_{x\to 2} f(x+2) + \lim \limits_{x\to 2} f(x^2) = 3$

Comment: I hope your question assumes that $\lim_{x\to 4}f(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not reduce generality by assuming $f$ continuous at $x=2$ (we know that the limit exists), and the question can be simply solved as

$$\frac{f(4)+3f(4)}{2^2+1}=3\implies f(4)=\frac{15}4.$$

Comment: @RushabhMehta: because it is convenient to set $f(4)=\lim_{x\to4}f(x)$, and *this does not reduce the generality*.

Comment: @RushabhMehta: no, this does not reduce generality, the value of $f(4)$ is in fact immaterial. This is just a matter of convenience, I don't want to introduce a heavy notation such as $f^*(x):= f(x) \land f^*(4)=\lim_{x\to4}f(x)$ and blahblah.

Answer (score 0):

For the first limit, do the variable change $u = x+2$, so that $u \to 4$ as $x \to 2$, giving
$$ \lim_{x\to 2} f(x+2) =\lim_{u\to 2} f(u), $$
and for the second limit, do the variable change $v = x^2$, so that $v \to 4$ as $x \to 2$, giving
$$ \lim_{x\to 2} f(x^2)=\lim_{v\to 2} f(v),  $$
so that the LHS of the final equality in your post is $$2\lim_{x\to 4} f(x). $$ Also, the RHS in that same equality is wrong, as pointed out by the others.

Comment: Sorry, could you please do more steps? I've been trying to do this but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there!

First, let's note that since $2^2+1=5$, so $\lim\limits_{x\to2}f(x+2)+3\lim_{x\to2}f(x^2)=15$, not $3$.

Next, note a very special property of $2$: $2^2=2+2$. This is important because we know then that $\lim\limits_{x\to2}f(x+2)=\lim\limits_{x\to2}f(x^2)=\lim\limits_{x\to4}f(x)$ as polynomials are continuous functions. Hence, $4\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to4}f(x)=15$ so $$\lim_{x\to4}f(x)=\color{red}{\frac{15}4}$$

Comment: It is nowhere said that $f$ is a polynomial function, and as you know, continuity at $x=4$ is not required.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I never said $f$ is polynomial. $x^2$ and $x+2$ are, which leads the limits to be the same. Please read before you downvote.

Comment: I'd be more comfortable upvoting if you were to explain why $\lim \limits_{x\to 2}\left(f(x+2)+3f\left(x^2\right)\right)$ exists and, at least state that $\lim \limits_{x\to 2}\left(f\left(x^2\right)\right)$ existing implies that $\lim \limits_{x\to 4}\left(f(x)\right)$. I do not agree that just saying $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous is convincing enough. In this context, if $\lim (\varphi \circ \psi)$ and $\lim \psi$ exist, you can't just say that $\lim \varphi$ exists without some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x+2)+3f(x^2)}{x^2+1}=3$$

Assuming the limits exist, we have $$\lim \limits_{x \to 2} {f(x+2)+3f(x^2)} = 3(2^2)+1=15$$

Thus $4 (\lim _{x\to 4} f(x))= 15 $ which results in $\lim _{x\to 4}=15/4$